# Inclusion Mapping?

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Is the hooked arrow map notation not supposed to mean an inclusion mapping?

[image: Miles Reid: Algebraic Geometry]

His definition is clearly showing inputs from $\mathbb{R}^2$ who's images are elements in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with fixed $z$ component 1. Am I missing something or is this clearly not an inclusion mapping?

Comment: In what sense is it not?

Comment: Hooked arrow can also mean embedding, not just straight inclusion.

Comment: @MikeMiller what element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @xyzzyz that is good to know, thank you.